# Swagger UI won't execute requests with Authorization header

Tags: java, http, servlets, openapi, swagger-codegen

I have set this:

```yaml
    securitySchemes:
          cookieAuth:
            type: apiKey
            in: header
            name: Authorization
```

and I go ahead and add a value to authorization there in the UI (which by the way I don't know if the text is supposed to be underlined with red there)

But then I hit execute and Swagger won't even send the request (I am on servlets), it just shouts immediately "Failed to fetch." etc.

I have set security as follows at the root of the YAML file:

```yaml
security:
  - cookieAuth: [ ]
```

And the curl request that gets generated is this:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost:8080/beautifulapi/users' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: adsdsdasas'
```

And without setting authorization header it works as expected. And from curl as well with authorization. But I need authorization header here in Swagger.
So why is it mad at me?

edit:
It doesn't work no matter which header I am setting (instead of authorization).

Comment: What is the error message in the Console tab of the browser dev tools?

Comment: I'm using it in IntelliJ IDE with the code generator so I don't have a console or browser dev tools. I don't know how to open it this way :( Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to put security in your path in [] because it's an array.

```
security: [{
      ApiKeyAuth: []
}],
```

For me this was the fix: [Swagger bearerAuth token block request from UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68560619/swagger-bearerauth-token-block-request-from-ui)