# Swagger bearerAuth token block request from UI

Tags: node.js, authentication, swagger-ui, openapi

I am using the swagger UI interface to test my node js requests.
I added the Authentication for those requests but when I try them in swagger I have the following issue:
If I add a bearerAuth token in the swagger UI When I click on execute in one of my requests, they are not executed. If I don't put a bearerAuth token my request plays as intended.

To add a token I added those options :

```
const openApi = OpenAPI({
    schema,
    info: {
      title: '**** API',
      version: '1.0.0',
    },
    components: {
      securitySchemes: {
        bearerAuth: {
          type: 'http',
          scheme: 'bearer',
          bearerFormat: 'JWT',
        },
      },
    },
    security: {
      bearerAuth: [],
    },
  });
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console in Swagger UI?

Comment: Yes there is :
system.js:490 TypeError: p.forEach is not a function
    at t.request (build-request.js:123)
    at ir (build-request.js:20)
    at Object.fr [as buildRequest] (index.js:255)
    at actions.js:452
    at utils.js:177
    at bindActionCreators.js:3
    at wrap-actions.js:33
    at Object.r (system.js:175)
    at Object.executeRequest (system.js:487)
    at actions.js:499

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`security` must be an array:

```js
    security: [
      { bearerAuth: [] }
    ],
```